# Are billable quotas applied to bandwidth between 2 apps in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Our web app is in python, but one of the libraries we need to use is only available in java. As a result, a lot of data has to be passed from the java app to the python app. Are billable quotas applied to the bandwidth between apps?

In Amazon, it is free to transfer data between instances.

Comment: if your running java and python apps on different appids your more than likely in breach of the terms of use.  You can run them in the same instance using different versions and then they have shared cache.  Maybe you could use a backend for the java component.

Comment: I didn't know it is possible to run java and python apps on with the same app ids. Is it possible to completely block the java version from  traffic splitting to versions?

Comment: you probably couldn't block all possible traffic, but someone would have to guess the name of the service.  I would also look closely at the role backends could play.  What sort of service do you need to run on java. The other advantage of this approach (single app multiple versions) is the java and python share the same memcache and datastore.

Comment: We need to run some scientific library which is currently only open sourced in java.

Comment: No, he's not in violation of the ToS doing this, but it would still be a better idea to run it as alternate versions of the same app.

Comment: GAE modules now allow to execute code for different runtimes (Java and Python, for example) in the same application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you're using URLFetch for the communication. If app1 sends a request of 100 bytes and gets a response of 1000 bytes from app2, app1 will be charged for 100 bytes of outgoing bandwidth and 1000 bytes of incoming bandwidth; app2 will be charged 100 bytes incoming and 1000 bytes outgoing. Using HTTPS instead of HTTP will count against the secure transfer quotas.

Comment: incoming bandwith is not billed.

Comment: True, but there is a quota for free apps.