# Does Google App Engine charge for network traffic between apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, cost-management

I am going to build an API for my mobile app using GAE. I am looking for a way to separate the whole application into separate services, trying out the microservice architecture.

The problem is there seems to be no information about any VPN or private network between GAE apps. Therefore, based on my understanding, when one of the GAE apps sends HTTP requests to other GAE apps in same account, its traffic will be treated as Internet traffic and therefore I will be charged for outbound bandwidth.

Am I correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are billable quotas applied to bandwidth between 2 apps in app engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422826/are-billable-quotas-applied-to-bandwidth-between-2-apps-in-app-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

App Engine applications/Cloud Platform projects are isolated from each other by default, even if they were created using the same Google account.

Consider looking into [Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) (link for Java) to implement individual services of your application.

Comment: Use modules. Multiple GAEs for one app will break the TOS because of possible abuse of free quotas.

Comment: They only break the TOS when you are running multiple projects with the same functionality to circumvent billing, but not if you run distinct functionality in each project. In this case: Modules have the clear disadvantage, that each module spins up a new instance, which costs about $40 a month, even for nothing. Cheapest: If you want to isolate code, write a separate library and bind it to the main module during compile, then everything will run in the same instance. Still a bit of fiddling and not so clean, but way cheaper.